# Align php div in a form

Tags: php, css, html

I have a php form and also the css code. I am trying to modify it so the message field goes to the right. I tried to put the Name and Email fields inside a div and the message and submit fields inside another div, then put these two inside a third div but I can't make it work, the best I got was to move all the fields to the right, but that is not what I want. I don't know php so not sure if it should work like it does in html.

I already customized it all I could but to align the div's horizontally is my problem.

You can see what I want to achieve in the below image.

[image]

I tried to put the code here in the right way but I can't do it. Sorry for that, I am new with all this stuff. So below there is a link from where you can download the files.

The files I have been working with are: 'contactform.php' and 'contact.css'

[php and css files](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26373038/simple-contact-form-1-2.zip)

Comment: You could just put the php/css into a fiddle, instead of expecting us to donwload a .zip

Comment: I know, like I said in my message I am new with all this stuff and I couldn't figure out the way to put the code into a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first we need to increase the width of the fieldset:

```
#contactus fieldset {
    width: 580px;
}
```

Now create two divs. One around the Name and Email fields and one around Message and Submit.

Finally set the style attribute (or better use classNames) with either `float: left;` or `float: right;`.

That's it. Hope it helps?!